# I cannot remove my broken package which I didn't install

Tags: apt, package-management, dependencies

```
sudo dpkg --remove --force-remove-reinstreq dotnet-runtime-2.0.0
dpkg: warning: ignoring request to remove dotnet-runtime-2.0.0 which isn't installed
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 dotnet-sdk-2.2 : Depends: aspnetcore-runtime-2.2 (>= 2.2.3) but it is not going to be installed
                  Depends: dotnet-runtime-2.2 (>= 2.2.3) but it is not going to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

Answer (score 2):

The error tells you  that `dotnet-sdk` depends on `dotnet-runtime`.

```
sudo apt remove dotnet-sdk
```

should prevent that error in the future.

Comment: i cant its not installed so it wont remove it